# Java вопрос по регулярным выражениям, удалить все знаки препинания

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка

```
String st = "Один, два! три? Четыре:";
```

Нужно удалить из неё все знаки препинания методом `.replace` или подобным ему.
Пробовал так:

```
String st2 = st.replace(",", "").replace("!", "").replace("?", "").replace(":", "");
```

Но мне кажется с помощью регулярных выражений (в которых я к сожалению не силён) это можно записать короче, подскажите каким образом сократить этот код.

Comment: В регулярных выражениях есть класс знаков пунктуации `\p{P}`.

Comment: Ещё рекомендую `\p{Punct}` и `\p{S}`, могут пригодиться.

Answer (score -1):

Привожу пример с заменами в строке через регулярные выражения:

```
public class RegexTestStrings {
    public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "This is my small example "
            + "string which I'm going to " + "use for pattern matching.";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.matches("\\w.*"));
        String[] splitString = (EXAMPLE_TEST.split("\\s+"));
        System.out.println(splitString.length);// should be 14
        for (String string : splitString) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        // replace all whitespace with tabs
        System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.replaceAll("\\s+", "\t"));
    }
}
```

Пример взят отсюда: [Using regular expressions with String methods](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Дополнительная информация легко гуглится.

Про варианты регулярных выражений рекомендую почитать здесь: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score -4):

```
String st2 = st.replace("([?!:;,])", "")
```

В квадратных скобках перечисление вариантов одного символа, а круглые означают отдельную часть.

Comment: Как минимум - нужно использовать `replaceAll`, а не `replace`, а вообще лучше вот так: `st.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "")` - удалятся все знаки пунктуации.